# Does anyone have any 2ed fillable character sheets?

Tags: adnd-2e, tool-recommendation, character-sheets

Does anyone have any 2ed fillable character sheets? I'm looking mostly for a mage. Most sheets out there cover all classes, and are huge and unorganized. I had hoped to find one for a mage, however.

Comment: I would love to, only wish I was smarter.

Comment: Are you looking for printable Character sheets?

Comment: There are some fillable ones on google drive, but they are ok at best, had hope to find more specific class ones, that can be on on computer and easily updated.

Comment: really? How is this shopping? At no point there is nothing about buying or selling anything, so no 1 iota of anything about shopping. A charactor sheet is needed and required by and an all who play this game, I also assume that this question answered could help other players, esp seeing 2ed edition ended "sorta" so many years ago.

Comment: @DerkDarringer please read the links given in the "off-topic" banner (specifically [Are Game Recommendation Questions On Topic, Revisited](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5747/14878) or the not-linked-above [Are tool recommendation questions on topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5883/14878)) for a better understanding of what a "shopping" question is in this context and consider checking out the [meta-tag:faq] tag over on [meta] to learn more about the site's policies.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.